# A function of comma

Tags: sentence-construction, commas

> The district he named ***is*** ***in the extreme east of the
>   country***, ***just on the borders of three states***, Transylvania,
>   Moldavia, and Bukovina, ***in the midst of the Carpathian
>   mountains***. (Dracula, Bram Stoker)

Reading a book, I saw this sentence above. As far as I understand, a comma can be used between objects of the same verb?

I think that sentence I quoted consist of those sentence below:

> 1- The district ***is*** in the extreme east of the country.
>
> 2- The district ***is*** on the borders of three states.
>
> 3- The district ***is*** in the midst of the Carpathian mountains.

So the sentence I quoted is a compressed form of those sentence (1+2+3). Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common to have multiple prepositional phrases in a sentence. Here each phrase is a complement of the verb "is", and describes the location of the district. Your analysis of the meaning is correct.

It's not really a compressed form, but you could perhaps say that your three sentences are an expanded form of the normal sentence written in Dracula.